# livereload doesn't work with gulp using watch

Tags: javascript, gulp, livereload

Not sure what is wrong, when I save index.html it build the stuff properly but it doesn't refresh like I normally use livereload. Below is my gulpfile.js

```
var env        = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2)),
    gulp       = require('gulp'),
    compass    = require('gulp-compass'),
    cssmin     = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    connect    = require('gulp-connect')


gulp.task('js', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('src/templates/**/*.html',['html']);
    gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', ['compass']);
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch('src/img/**/*.{jpg,png,gif}', ['imagemin']);
});

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: ['build/'],
        livereload: true,
        middleware: function(){
            return [
                modRewrite([
                    '^/$ /index.html',
                    '^([^\\.]+)$ $1.html'
                ])
            ];
        }
    });
});
gulp.task('default', ['js','html','watch','connect']);
```

Any idea what's wrong?